# Angular CDK - overlay attach to target while scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am trying to implement an Overlay with the Angular CDK. The Overlay is used inside a container that has a horizontal scroll. If we scroll to the left side the overlay should stick to the original position or disappear.

I could successfully implement this behavior by using the CDK directives. (Open the overlay by clicking on the open button and scroll to the left). The overlay follows the button.

[Stackblitz example that uses the directives](https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-scroll-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I try to achieve the same without the directives but with the usage of the Overlay service.

[Stackblitz example that uses the services](https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-scroll-code?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In this case, the overlay stays and doesn't move with the content. I need to use the service over the directive because we will encapsulate this behind a custom directive. Any ideas on how to achieve the same behavior with the services as with the directives are very welcome? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve that behavior with the following configuration:

```
this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
  scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition(), // remove autoClose: true option
  hasBackdrop: false,
  positionStrategy: this.overlay
    .position()
    .flexibleConnectedTo(this.button)
    .setOrigin(this.button)
    .withScrollableContainers([this.scrollContainer])
    .withPositions([                                         // correct this as you want
      {
        originX: "start",
        originY: "bottom",
        overlayX: "start",
        overlayY: "top"
      }
    ])
    .withFlexibleDimensions(false)                          // add this
    .withPush(false)                                       // add this
});
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-scroll-code-hpgq9f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Wow. Awesome. Thx a lot @yurzui.  You saved my day 